# jquery - stopping auto play after 10 seconds - RoundAbout

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow

I'm using [RoundAbout](http://fredhq.com/projects/roundabout/) plugin to make an slideshow with AutoPlay. It's working fine but i want to stop the autoplay after few seconds. I read the documentation and tried "autoplayDuration" but its not what it seems :P

So, any tip or hint how can i do that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You'd use a callback on start. Something like:

```
function stopRoundaboutAfterAWhile() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        .roundabout("stopAutoplay");
    }, 10000);
}

.roundabout(options, stopRoundaboutAfterAWhile)
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution for this was calling autoplay when the page is ready and mixing with setTimeout.

Also I stopped the autoplay in random seconds and saved the div ID on localStorage.

```
$(window).load(function() {
            $('ul').roundabout();
            $('ul').roundabout('startAutoplay');

            var tempo = Math.floor(Math.random()*(10000-5000+1))+5000;

            setTimeout(function(){
                $('ul').roundabout('stopAutoplay');
            }, tempo);

            setTimeout(function(){
                console.log($('.roundabout-in-focus').attr('id'));
                window.localStorage.setItem('vilao',$('.roundabout-in-focus').attr('id'));
            }, tempo + 1000);

    });
```